# Laravel: how to not require login after make:auth

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I just ran `php artisan make:auth` on my app which made it so that nothing can be accessed on the app without logging in.

I want some content to be visible to guest users, but don't know how. Let's say I just want them to be able to see the home page, the page they get directed to when they go to `localhost:8000`, instead of being instantly redirected to the `localhost:8000/login` page. How do I do this?

Comment: It is about routing. [This documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing) might help you. Take time to understand it but it is definitely worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You may add guest access within a specific controller, like so:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', [ 'except' => 'logout' ]);
}
```

in the example above, all functions in the controller are accessible to *guests* except `logout`, for which you must be logged in.

or within a router:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function(){
    Route::get(...
});
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home')->middleware('guest');
```